# Is there any way to change default datatype(CSV) to MySQL datatypes dynamically

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I want to transfer the CSV data to MySQL table.

I have read CSV, which contains all types of data with below command :
file = pd.read_csv('abc.csv')

To transfer to MySQL used below command :
file.to_sql(con=engine, name='abc', if_exists='replace', index=True, dtype=None, method=None)

This sends the data into MySQL table but it takes datatype as "text","bigint" but I want it as "varchar" & "int"....

CSV has 50 columns, so to overcome this issue I tried for 3 fields only, with dtype={'index': sql_types.INT, 'Employee ID': sql_types.INT, 'Employee Name': sql_types.VARCHAR(255)} and it worked!

Now I have to add remaining 47 fields to this dtype dictionary,

so I want to know, Is there any way to convert the data type automatically without mentioning its column name, like.., when fields is numeric convert it to INT, when fields is alphanumeric convert it to VARCHAR, When fields is date type convert it to datetime and these three lines will be enough.

Answer (score 1):

After reading in the CSV you can loop through the cols and change them:

```
for col in list(df):
    if df[col].dtype == 'O':
        df[col] == df[col].astype(sql_types.VARCHAR(255))
    elif df[col].dtype == 'int':
        df[col] == df[col].astype(sql_types.INT)
```

This is assuming you have imported these `sql_types` from somewhere, because they aren't Pandas builtins. But you said that you were able to use them.

If you have date format, you can do a try/except to convert to `pd.datetime` and if so save them as SQL date type.